# How to Video Call Another Person Pragmatically In Agora Like Accept Call ,Reject Call Same As Whats app in Android?

Tags: android

I Need a proper Integration Sample of Video Calling Using Agora SDK In Android Like Login user,Enter recipient detail whom you want to call, after that call should be connected between user and  receiver and receiver has option to accept and reject call.if he accept call then they could talk together like normal call.
Actually i am new for video calling integration.

Answer (score 0):

Agora has a few sample apps which helps achieve a "call" functionality using Agora's Video and Real-Time Messaging SDKs along with Android's ConnectionService.
Check out the below link for the same.
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling